# Using Octodiff with Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

So I am using "Octodiff" found here:

https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Octodiff

in Unity 5. Unfortunately, Unity 5 only supports .Net 2.0 at the moment. "Octodiff" is written for .net 4. So I have had to find ways to get it to work. So I am using the following libaries:

Tuples:
https://gist.github.com/michaelbartnett/5652076

.Net4 In C#:https://github.com/mono/mono

Wrote my own "string.IsNullOrEmptyString()"

The problem is that I thought the following libraries from ".Net In C#":

istructuralcomparable.cs

istructuralequatable.cs

structuralcomparisions.cs

would allow me to fix the following code.

```
 if (!StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(BinaryFormat.SignatureHeader, header)) 
            throw new CorruptFileFormatException("The signature file appears to be corrupt.");
```

and

```
if (!StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(BinaryFormat.EndOfMetadata, endOfMeta)) 
            throw new CorruptFileFormatException("The signature file appears to be corrupt.");
```

While it compiles correctly I think that code I got is a little different because it is failing the above checks.

**Is there A way I can use "StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals" from the .Net 4 Libraries in .Net 2.0 in Unity?**

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I actually did to a certain extent. It's really not polished and still has a few bugs but I wrote a C# script that is to be used in Unity that will take advantage of it here: https://github.com/wesleywh/GameDevRepo/tree/master/Scripts/Patching the documentation for it is here: https://github.com/wesleywh/GameDevRepo/wiki/Patch-System if nothing else this will help you get a head start.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Never thought it would be this hard to find a windows rsync alternative :(

Comment: Note: that my above repo, while it does use octodiff, had to comment out the sections asked for above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to use the library, no. But that doesn't mean you can't use octodiff at all!

If you're only targetting windows with your game, just call/control octodiff from the commandline (`Process.Start(...)`)